# How to make multi language editor dynamic list of language?

Tags: vuejs3

On vuejs3 site I need to make multi language editor where list of language can be changed and I load it server's side into locales var.
But using Fields from vee-validate library in v-for :

```
    <div v-for="locale in locales" :key="locale.id"> <!-- description FIELD DEFINITION -->
      <div >
        <label class="col-form-label" for="description">Description<span >{{locale}}</span></label>
      </div>
      <div >
        <Field
            name="description"
            as="textarea"
            rows="8"
            class="form-control editable_field"
            v-model="formDescription[locale]">
        </Field>
        <ErrorMessage name="description" as="p" class="validation_error"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I got error :

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:40 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function
  at <Form onSubmit=fn<onSubmit> validation-schema= ObjectSchema {type: 'object', _whitelist: ReferenceSet(0), _blacklist: ReferenceSet(0), internalTests: {…}, _typeCheck: ƒ, …} class="bannerEdit" >
  at <BannerEditPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {…} > >
  at <RouterView>
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:40
logError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:230
handleError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:222
renderComponentRoot @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:943
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5720
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:190
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5763
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:173
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:406
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:298
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:292
eval @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5761
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:390
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1021
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1066
eval @ Banner.vue?d3f2:596
Promise.then (async)
loadBanner @ Banner.vue?d3f2:556
eval @ Banner.vue?d3f2:420
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:173
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:182
job @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:1812
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:173
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:406
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:298
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:292
scheduler @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:1845
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:390
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:373
set @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:675
emit @ eventBus.js?3195:7
eval @ commonFuncs.js?a7a0:100
Promise.then (async)
retrieveAppDictionaries @ commonFuncs.js?a7a0:31
bannerEditOnMounted @ Banner.vue?d3f2:379
eval @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2756
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:173
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:182
hook.__weh.hook.__weh @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2731
flushPostFlushCbs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:359
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:413
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:298
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:292
eval @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5761
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:390
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1021
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1158
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:385
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1021
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1158
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:385
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1021
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1158
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:385
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1021
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1158
triggerEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:400
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:385
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1021
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1066
finalizeNavigation @ vue-router.mjs?f169:3334
eval @ vue-router.mjs?f169:3207
Promise.then (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.mjs?f169:3173
push @ vue-router.mjs?f169:3099
install @ vue-router.mjs?f169:3530
use @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4399
eval @ main.js?fbea:27
./src/main.js @ app.js:151
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:758
(anonymous) @ app.js:1950
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:807
(anonymous) @ app.js:1951
(anonymous) @ app.js:1953
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:40 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core
  at <Form onSubmit=fn<onSubmit> validation-schema= ObjectSchema {type: 'object', _whitelist: ReferenceSet(0), _blacklist: ReferenceSet(0), internalTests: {…}, _typeCheck: ƒ, …} class="bannerEdit" >
  at <BannerEditPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {…} > >
  at <RouterView>
  at <App>
```

Looks like this error was raised by code :

```
v-model="formDescription[locale]"
```

But code :

```
v-model="formDescription"
```

works ok.

in which way multi language editor can be done here?

In package.json:

```
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"vee-validate": "^4.7.4",
"vue": "^3.2.13",
```

Thanks in advance!